# 'Ambiguous EJB reference "beanName" or more precise "beanInterface" should be specified'

Tags: intellij-idea, ejb-3.0

I have a multi-module project where the EJB `BarService` in project `bar` refers to a `FooService` EJB in `foo` project. The `@EJB` annotation is use to inject the EJB.

```
@EJB
private FooService fooService;
```

I'm using IntellijIDEA 11, and it complains with

> 'Ambiguous EJB reference "beanName" or more precise "beanInterface" should be specified'.

This error is only showing up for EJB references in a different module. If I use the `beanName` as suggested, the error goes away. However I would prefer not to use it, since it would be hard to refactor the component name as it is a string.

Is this a bug in IDEA, or am I trying to do something wrong here?

(Noticed [this](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/292911) and [this](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5240260;jsessionid=350F51116852173795395139FB9B3B08) asking the exact same question in the JetBrains forums, but there are no replies sadly).

Comment: IntelliJ does refactor the beanName as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc for [javax.ejb.EJB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) is somewhat unclear on this point:

> If no explicit linking information is provided and there is only one
>   session bean **within the same application** that exposes the matching
>   client view type, by default the EJB dependency resolves to that
>   session bean.

It's debatable whether application in this context means "EJB module" or "EAR", so I don't necessarily think IDEA is to blame.  I'm not familiar with other vendors, but at least WebSphere Application Server will attempt to disambiguate within the client EJB/WAR module before considering all EJBs in all modules in the EAR.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bkail. I guess we will have to just live with this minor nuisance.